# How do I clear the screen using Jansi?

Tags: java, command-line-interface, ansi-escape, jansi

I am trying to clear the console in Java using Jansi. I am using macOS, but Jansi should be portable.

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
AnsiConsole.systemInstall();

System.out.println("Hello... ");
System.out.println(Ansi.ansi().eraseScreen());
System.out.println("... world.");
```

However, this does not clear the screen. It inserts many new lines and then prints the next line, like this:

```
Hello...






 ... world.
```

How do I clear the screen properly, so that my final output is just the below?

```
... world.
```

Comment: Have you tried [`Ansi#eraseScreen(Ansi.Erase)`](http://fusesource.github.io/jansi/documentation/api/org/fusesource/jansi/Ansi.html#eraseScreen-org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi.Erase-) and using one of the other erase methods?  It might not be possible and might be limitation of the API

Comment: @MadProgrammer Just tried it; it has the same problem.

Comment: Your examplecode worked correctly when running in a console under Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try by overwriting the world "Hello..." with "...world".

It should be something like this:

```
System.out.print("Hello... ");
System.out.print(ansi().cursorLeft("Hello... ".lenght()).a("...world"));
```